# Display custom entity based on two class (ViewModel and Domain Model)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, infragistics, ignite-ui

Hi im making a project using asp.net mvc 4.0 , with entity framework  and linq...
So i have two classes.
Cliente Class:

```
namespace LicenciamentoMVC.Models
{
public class Cliente
{
    [Key]
    public int IDCliente { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Morada { get; set; }
    public string CPostal { get; set; }
    public string Localidade { get; set; }
    public string Freguesia { get; set; }
    public string Conselho { get; set; }
    public string Distrito { get; set; }
    public string Pais { get; set; }
    public string Telefone { get; set; }
    public string Telemovel { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Nif { get; set; }
    public string WWW { get; set; }
    public string Observacoes { get; set; }
    public int IDP { get; set; }
    public int IDU { get; set; }
    public DateTime TStamp { get; set; }
    public int Rem { get; set; }
    public String TipoCliente { get; set; }

}
public class ClienteModel
{
    private static Cliente entity;
    public static IQueryable<Cliente> GetListaClientes()
    {
        MvcApplication1Context db = new MvcApplication1Context();

        var customers = from c in db.Clientes
                        orderby c.IDCliente descending
                        where c.Rem==0
                        select c;

        return customers.AsQueryable<Cliente>();
    }
  }
}
```

and here is my Processo Class

```
  public class Processo
{
    [Key]
    public int IDProcesso { get; set; }
    public int IDCliente { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataInserido { get; set; }
    public string NumeroFactura { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataFactura { get; set; }
    public string Estado { get; set; }
    public int IDU { get; set; }
    public int Rem { get; set; }
    public DateTime TStamp { get; set; }

}
```

Lets say i want to view the the IDprocesso and DataInserido from class Processo, and Nome from class Cliente.

My database is composed of two tables Clientes and Processos.
My dbContent Class:

```
public class MvcApplication1Context:DbContext
{
    public MvcApplication1Context()
        : base("name=MvcApplication1Context")
    {
    }

    //protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    //{
    //    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    //}
    public DbSet<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Processo> Processos { get; set; }
 }
```

The method GetListClientes is an iqueryable because i am using Igniteui components, in this case igGrid and i followed a tutorial that i found in the infragistics site, if there is a better way to do this, please tell me..

Back to the topic..
I didnt declare the foreign keys because of problem with contrains..
Should i create a new class with the fields that i want to see , or is there another way.
if i go with the method of create a new class for showing the data i should do something like this inside that class:

```
public class ProcessoClienteModel
{
    private static ProcessoCliente entity;
    public static IQueryable<ProcessoCliente> GetListaProcessos()
    {
        MvcApplication1Context db = new MvcApplication1Context();

        var processos = from p in db.Processos
                        from c in db.Clientes
                        orderby p.IDProcesso descending
                        where p.IDCliente == c.IDCliente

                        where p.Rem == 0
                        select new { p.processoID,p.DataInserido,c.Nome} as  IQueryable<ClienteModel>;
        return processos;


        return processos.AsQueryable<ProcessoCliente>();
    }

}
```

Or is there a better way for doing this...
I am going through topics on internet trying to find a way..
Thanks for the help..

So i have been trying to find a way and the thing that i am trying to make is a viewmodel class, in this view model i will have the fields that i want to display, the Processo id, Data Inserido and the name of the cliente..and this class wil fetch value through linq to my domain class, in this case processo and cliente...
Am i going in the right direction???

Using the tip that Bjorn Vdkerckhove gave me, thanks, i have done this..
Create a new folder called viewmodel, and inside create a new class called ProcessoCliente.cs
The code of this class:

```
namespace LicenciamentoMVC.ModelsView
{
public class ProcessoCliente
{
    public int IDProcesso { get; set; }
    public string NomeCliente { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataInserido { get; set; }
}
public class ProcessoModel
{
    private static ProcessoCliente entity;
    public static IQueryable<ProcessoCliente> GetListaProcessosClientes()
    {
        MvcApplication1Context db = new MvcApplication1Context();

        var processos =  (from p in db.Processos
                         join c in db.Clientes on p.IDCliente equals c.IDCliente
                          orderby p.IDProcesso descending
                         select new ProcessoCliente { IDProcesso = p.IDProcesso, NomeCliente = c.Nome, DataInserido = p.DataInserido});


        return processos.AsQueryable<ProcessoCliente>();
    }

}
}
```

then i create the view on the index action of controller Processo

```
@model IEnumerable<LicenciamentoMVC.ModelsView.ProcessoCliente>
@using Infragistics.Web.Mvc

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@* render of ignite ui grid *@
@( Html.Infragistics().Grid<LicenciamentoMVC.ModelsView.ProcessoCliente>()

    .Caption("Processos")
    .ID("grid1")
    .DefaultColumnWidth("200px")
    .PrimaryKey("IDProcesso")
    .Columns(column =>
    {

        column.For(x =>x.NomeCliente).DataType("string").HeaderText("Nome do Cliente").Width("60%");
        column.For(x => x.DataInserido).DataType("DateTine").HeaderText("Data de Criação do Processo").Width("40%");

        column.For(x => x.IDProcesso).DataType("int").Width("0%");




    })
    .Features(features =>
    {
        features.Paging().PageSize(20).PrevPageLabelText("Previous").NextPageLabelText("NEXT");
        features.Sorting().Mode(SortingMode.Single).ColumnSettings(settings =>
        {
            settings.ColumnSetting().ColumnKey("NomeCliente").AllowSorting(true);

        });
        features.Selection().MultipleSelection(false).Mode(SelectionMode.Row);
        features.Filtering().Mode(FilterMode.Simple);
        features.Updating()
               .EnableAddRow(false)
               .EnableDeleteRow(true)
               .EditMode(GridEditMode.None);




    })
    .DataSourceUrl(Url.Action("ListarProcessos"))    
    .UpdateUrl(Url.Action("DeleteProcessos"))        
   .AutofitLastColumn(false)
   .Width("100%")
    .AutoGenerateColumns(false)
    .DataBind()
    .Render()
)
```

And i have this action inside ProcessoController to load the grid..

```
    [GridDataSourceAction]
    public ActionResult ListarProcessos()
    {
        return View(LicenciamentoMVC.ModelsView.ProcessoModel.GetListaProcessosClientes());
    }
```

It works, but i would like to know if this is the right way to go...or there is a better way to do it..

Thanks again,..

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any real relation between the objects if i understand you correctly. It all depends on how much data you need to show.

If you want to show related data, you can do this on your view with razor:

```
@foreach(var client in Model.Clientes)
{
 <h1>@client.Name</h1>
<ul>
<li>Model.Processo.FirstOrDefault(f=> f.IDCliente == client.IDCliente).DataInserido.toString("dd-MM-yyyy")</li>
<li>.... other properties...</li>
</ul>
}
```

Comment: the connection is between IDCliente from processo, and IDCliente from cliente...I didnt use foreign key because of contrains problems..

Comment: I changed my code to IDCliente. This way you can access the properties

Comment: ok, but now the problem is related with igniteui component...that receives an iqueryable...

Comment: If your component needs an iqueryable, then yes, you will need to create a new poco and return a new iqueryable of that poco.

Comment: so if i understande i should create a viewmodel that receives the values that will be display in the view???

Comment: If your ui component needs a list of items as datasource, then yes